# virtualenv --relocatable with windows?

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv that I need to be relocatable (as per a previous question). I'm trying to use the --relocatable option.

I'm doing this on a windows box.

However, I get `Script C:\.......activate.ps1 cannot be made relative (it's not a normal script that starts with #!c:\users\......\python.exe)`

Similarly with deactivate.bat. And it doesn't look like it even TRIED to work on activate.bat...